# AngularJS - ng-if runs digest loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

I am facing problem with infinite loop on loading the view. The data is loaded from an API call using ngResource in the controller. The view seems to be reloaded multiple times before rendering the view correctly. I use ng directives in the template calling scope methods and this seems to get into loop causing the view to be re-rendered.

Here is my Controller

```
.controller('IndexCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'ProfileInfo',
function($scope, $stateParams, ProfileInfo) {
    $scope.navTitle = 'Profile Information';

    $scope.data = {};

    ProfileInfo.query({
        id: $stateParams.id
    }).$promise.then(function(Profile) {

        if (Profile.status == 200) {
            $scope.data.Profile = Profile.data[0];
          }else{
             console.log(Profile.status);
          }

    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    $scope.showImageBlock = function(object, image) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty('type') && object.type == 'image') {
                imageReference = object.value;
                var imageUrl;
                angular.forEach(image, function(value, key) {
                    if (value.id == imageReference) {
                      $scope.data.imageUrl = value.graphic.url;
                        return;
                    }
                });
            }
            return object.hasOwnProperty('type') && object.type == 'image';
        };

        $scope.showText = function(object) {
            console.log('text');
            return object.hasOwnProperty('type') && object.type == 'text';
        };

}
])
```

And Here is my template

```
<ion-view cache-view="false">
<ion-nav-title>
    {{navTitle}}
</ion-nav-title>
<div class="bar bar-subheader bar-light">
    <h2 class="title">{{navSubTitle}}</h2>
</div>
<ion-content has-header="true" padding="true" has-tabs="true" class="has-subheader">
    <div ng-repeat="profileInfo in data.Profile">
        <div class="list">
            <img ng-if="showImageBlock(profileInfo,data.Profile.images)"  ng-src="{{ data.imageUrl }}" class="image-list-thumb" />
            <div ng-if="showText(profileInfo)">
                <a class="item">
                    {{profileInfo.name}}
                  <span ng-if="profileInfo.description.length != 0"class="item-note">
                    {{profileInfo.description}}
                  </span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here is the output of console window when tried log the number of times showText function is called.

[image: Console Output]

The actual result from ngResource call has only 9 items in array but it loops more than 9 times and also multiple loops. This happens for a while and stops. Could anyone please point me in the right direction in fixing it.

Thank you

Comment: can you provide [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: create a plunker so that we can see also see the log activity.

Comment: also functions inside view evaluate on each digest loop, so if you do something in another place that call digest loop, your view would be updated and all functions in view will be execute

Comment: @Grundy here is the the link to codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpYpvj?editors=101

Comment: but I am not able to replicate the issue in codepen. Is there any way to identify what is causing the issue?

Comment: you can reproduce it: you have `8` profile, but in output you have `16` messages with text. also as i understand this a simplified sample, and really you have a bit more markup?

Comment: yes.. I have got bit more markup on the actual page. And the loop at times runs for over 1000 cycle. and I am not able to identify what is causing the issue.

Comment: do you have any handlers for mousemove,mouseenter and etc events? Seems like this how work ng-repeat. and i have only one suggest - not use function in view side, for example in this case you can reduce it to `<div ng-if="profileInfo.type=='text'">`

Comment: @Grundy I dont have any events on the template but all my templates have some complex ng-if checks and I am not sure whether I could add them all directly to ng-if. I thought having a function would make it simple. but why does using function in template causes issue in AngularJS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86777/discussion-between-grundy-and-h4v0ccr8or).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I ended up creating a custom directive which does the function of ng-if without the watchers which triggers the digest loop. It's not a pretty solution but it seems to do the job as expected. I copied the code of ng-if and removed the $scope watcher. Here is the custom directive.

```
angular.module('custom.directives', [])

.directive('customIf', ['$animate',function($animate) {
   return {
     multiElement: true,
     transclude: 'element',
     priority: 600,
     terminal: true,
     restrict: 'A',
     $$tlb: true,
     link: function($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl, $transclude) {
        var block, childScope, previousElements;
        value = $scope.$eval($attr.customIf);
        if (value) {
          if (!childScope) {
            $transclude(function(clone, newScope) {
              childScope = newScope;
              clone[clone.length++] = document.createComment(' end customIf: ' + $attr.customIf + ' ');
             block = {
              clone: clone
             };
             $animate.enter(clone, $element.parent(), $element);
           });
        }
      } 
      else {
        if (previousElements) {
           previousElements.remove();
           previousElements = null;
          }
        if (childScope) {
          childScope.$destroy();
          childScope = null;
        }
        if (block) {
          previousElements = getBlockNodes(block.clone);
          $animate.leave(previousElements).then(function() {
            previousElements = null;
          });
          block = null;
        }
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

This allows us to use the customIf as follows

```
<div custom-if="showText(profileInfo)">
```